# Did NVIDIA eventually drop old BIOS screen modes?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers, graphics-card, bios

I have a PC setup for *retro* gaming and development *(I say retro...it's running Windows XP and Windows 7, if you can call that retro these days)*.

I've tested three different graphics cards in this machine...

**NVIDIA GeForce 7800GTX (Asus)**

BIOS screen modes work fine on this card, but some more modern games that require DirectX are very laggy at higher resolutions.

**NVIDIA GeForce 8600GT (Asus)**

BIOS screen modes work fine on this card. Less laggy than above, but still noticeably laggy at higher resolutions.

**NVIDIA GeForce 9800GT (Nvidia)**

Only BIOS screen mode 0 (text mode) seems to work. I tried modes 12 (640x480x16) and 13 (320x200x256) but it just displays a blank screen. Handles higher resolutions nicely, although sounds like it's going to take off.

It would seem that the BIOS graphics modes (admittedly from the 80s) have been removed in the NVIDIA 9 series cards, but I was wondering...

1. Is there any technical documentation that will back up that claim?
2. Would this likely be vendor specific; i.e. if I were to obtain another 9 series card from, for example Asus, might the BIOS modes still be supported?

Comment: Support for XP is long gone (95%) and the remaining 5% is going fast. Old software is dying with it. Modernize to Windows 11.

Comment: Likely the [VBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_BIOS) becoming more UEFI aware necessitated removal of rarely used features in the firmware in favour of more UEFI orientated features due to limited space in the VBIOS. Indeed that wikipedia page says "In UEFI 2.x systems, the INT 10h and the VBE are replaced by the [UEFI GOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI_GOP)." so this seems to be a natural progression from BIOS to UEFI across the system.

Comment: While OEMs *might* be able to modify the VBIOS it is quite possible and likely that the actual code that runs on the GPU is a binary "microcode" blob provided by Nvidia that expects manufacturer card specific data blocks (for clock speeds, memory timings etc) to be provided by the manufacturer. The OEM *might* be able to add features back in, but given the proprietary nature of the silicon I would not expect anyone outside of Nvidia to have the knowledge or skill to modify the VBIOS without reference manuals and errata for each and every chip. Only comments due to this being mainly conjecture.

Comment: For the last 10 or so years Microsoft and Intel have been pushing to remove legacy and obsolete features from the platform in order to streamline and ease both software and hardware development, it makes sense that the same is happening with other components and that the newer components no longer support old modes. You may find sooner rather than later that you might be better off using virtual machines or emulator based solutions such as DosBox or QEMU (which do BIOS emulation) for your retro needs.

Comment: @John Windows 11 is hardly retro, is it? Besides, I have that running on my main computer.

Comment: I did not suggest that Windows 11 was retro. But new systems will not run old games. My point was to modernize your games so that new games will run on new systems.

Comment: @Mokubai I did consider DosBox or something like VirtualPC, but they also come with their limitations. I may just have to revert to an older card in this case.

Comment: regarding "laggy" performance, recall that many games of that time used hardware id lookup tables to tweak performance or specify alternate palette modes etc. If your card isn't in the table, then the default would be used and that default might be Least Common Denominator. Look to see if the game has exposed the table list and try adding your hardware id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screen modes are indicated to operating system by the card's firmware,
when the computer is booted.

It is logical that the firmware of newer cards does not support modes
that are no longer used in modern computers.

You will need to use an older card, to find these old modes.

Comment: As such, I've opted for the 8600GT which still supports the old int10h and VBE modes